# How do I construct DBUnit dataset/whatever to insert/clean a table with tree-like data

Tags: tree, hierarchy, hierarchical-data, dbunit

I have a very easy table (id, name, parent) that represents a tree. I want to use dbunit while testing this table, so I created a simple dataset for 2 nodes (yaml instead of xml for readability):

```
node:
  - id: 1
    name: default
    parent: null
  - id: 2
    name: default-child
    parent: 1
```

This gets inserted all right, but when trying to clean the table (I'm using DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT) it causes a constraint violation:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (node, CONSTRAINT FK_NODE.PARENT_TO_NODE.ID FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES node (id))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found  a workaround: using truncate_table operation instead of gentle clean operation works for me on mysql

Comment: You're using CLEAN_INSERT to clear the database? Wouldn't it be DELETE_ALL? How did you replace the strategy for database clean up? What language were you using? Any test framework linked to dbunit, like Spock or Mojito? I'm trying to accomplish something similar in Grails, but am failing miserably. Auto relations seem to mess up with MySQL mind...